# Change default new project's simulator in XCode 8

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, xcode8

Is there any preference selector or a way to change the default simulator for new projects in XCode 8? I'm currently using XCode 8.2, I'm kinda tired of changing the device I want to run my app on.